# unterminated conditional directive error in c

Tags: c

what is wrong with the following structs? I have attached an image of my code below. thanks.

```
#ifndef T2_H_ //here is the error: unterminated conditional directive
#define T2_H_
#define SIZE 40

typedef struct node {
int vertex;
struct node* list;
} node;

typedef struct adjList{
node *head_list;
int visited;
int arr_name;
} adjList;

typedef struct Graph {
int tot_vertices;
struct node** adjList; 

} Graph;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUK6l.png)

Comment: You're missing an `#endif` at the end of your file...

Answer (score 2):

The conditional directive (`#ifndef`) has not been terminated by an `#endif` somewhere else. You probably meant to put it at either the end of your file or on line 4.